# How can I split a string (String or &str) on more than one delimiter?

Tags: string, split, rust

I want to be able to separate the string `aabbaacaaaccaaa` on the strings `bb` and `cc` but not on `b` or `c`. The example would result in `aa,aacaaa,aaa`.

I already can split a string on a single delimiter, and the words() function splits a string on ,`\n` and `\t`, so I figured it must be possible.

Comment: With a regex? http://doc.rust-lang.org/regex/regex/index.html

Comment: This was [cross-posted to Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/30608a/split_string_on_multiple_delimiters/)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do this *with the standard library* right now. You **can** split on multiple `char` delimiters though, as `words` does. You need to give an array or slice of characters to `split`:

```rust
for part in "a,bc;d".split([',', ';']) {
    println!(">{}<", part);
}
```

If you try with strings, however:

```rust
for part in "a,bc;d".split([",", ";"]) {
    println!(">{}<", part);
}
```

You'll get the error:

```
error[E0277]: expected a `FnMut<(char,)>` closure, found `[&str; 2]`
 --> src/main.rs:2:32
  |
2 |     for part in "a,bc;d".split([",", ";"]) {
  |                          ----- ^^^^^^^^^^ expected an `FnMut<(char,)>` closure, found `[&str; 2]`
  |                          |
  |                          required by a bound introduced by this call
  |
  = help: the trait `FnMut<(char,)>` is not implemented for `[&str; 2]`
  = help: the following other types implement trait `Pattern<'a>`:
            &'b [char; N]
            &'b [char]
            [char; N]
  = note: required for `[&str; 2]` to implement `Pattern<'_>`
note: required by a bound in `core::str::<impl str>::split`
```

In nightly Rust, you could implement [`Pattern`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/pattern/trait.Pattern.html) for your own type that includes a slice of strings.

If you are cool with using a well-supported crate that isn't part of the standard library, you can use [regex](https://docs.rs/regex):

```rust
use regex; // 1.4.5

fn main() {
    let re = regex::Regex::new(r"bb|cc").unwrap();
    for part in re.split("aabbaacaaaccaaa") {
        println!(">{}<", part);
    }
}
```

Comment: @BurntSushi5 because I was only thinking of the standard library. I've updated with a regex example. You should have submitted an answer yourself; now I get all the sweet, sweet Internet points!

Comment: Haha that's OK. Comments are nice because they don't take much time. :-)

Comment: FYI, the `regex!` macro won't work on Rust 1.0 stable (the `plugin` feature will remain unstable). The standard `regex::Regex::new` way of making a regex will work though.

Comment: thanks a bundle! I've used the regex::new option and it works great!

Comment: @DavidRoundy thanks! Yeah, it's been nightly forever, so I'm not sure why I didn't mention that originally.

Comment: Why do you make the pattern `&[',', ';'][..]`? Simply `[',', ';']` seems to work equally well. Or is this something that has changed since 2015? :)

Comment: @Seriously yes, that appears to have been [added in Rust 1.58](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/86336)